# Snowsql not connecting

Tags: command, snowsql

I did install Snowsql 1.25. Installation went fine.
I configure the config file the the right account (xq59548.us-east-2.aws) user and password.

My .profile file seems fine and so is the $PATH:
[Error with zhh - command not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZpho.png)

Has anyone encoutered this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As I see, the path of Snowsql is missing. I can see that my path includes the following:

```
/Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Could you try to run it after adding the above path to your PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yep...The PATH was missing indeed.
The Python librairies were not visible by the z shell program.

I added a zprofile file at the root with the following:

alias snowsql=/Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/snowsql

And it worked fine. 
Funny that the SnowSQL installer does not create that file.

Thanks for your input bud!